# Are static variables in Objective-C methods shared across instances?

Tags: objective-c

I want to clarify whether different instances of an Objective-C class share static variables that occur inside methods, or if each instance gets its own copy:

```
- (void) myMethod {
    static int myVar = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's the same as a static variable in C; the instances will share the variable.  If you want each instance to have its own copy, you want an instance variable (declared in the `@interface` block).

Comment: You can't really say "same as C." "Subjective" C doesn't have instances in the Objective sense.

Comment: @iter, it's the same as any static variable in C, is all I mean.  If it's a static global there is only one per compilation unit, if it's a static local, there is one per function (or method in Objective-C) that references it.

Answer (score 88):

Static locals are shared between method calls AND instances.
You can think of them as globals which are visible only inside their methods:

```
- (void) showVars {
    int i = 0;
    static int j = 0;
    i++; j++;
    NSLog(@"i = %i ; j = %i", i, j);
}
```

[...]

```
[obj1 showVars];
[obj2 showVars];
[obj1 showVars];
[obj2 showVars];
```

Above calls on 2 different instances will output:

```
i = 1 ; j = 1
i = 1 ; j = 2
i = 1 ; j = 3
i = 1 ; j = 4
```

Comment: Any solution for instance-specific static local variables?

Comment: @fatuhoku what does that even mean? How are they static if they are instance-specific?

Comment: I think @fatuhoku is looking for something that would give the output sequence for `j` in the above example of `1 1 2 2` rather than `1 2 3 4`—that's what I came here looking for.